# The differences : 'industry' includes establishment, undertaking, work, trade, business and any other workplace;

Tags: employment

> In this Act, 'industry' includes establishment, undertaking, work, trade, business and any other workplace;

As a non English native speaker, sadly, I can't gasp the differences of the meanings of the words completely. Help me.

Answer (score 1):

An act of Parliament or Congress typically has a purpose for existing; it is to regulate some group(s) of people or organisations and their activity in a positive or negative fashion, and sometimes both. That is, the group must do or must not do some or all of the things in a given list or lists which is laid out by the Act itself.

The particular Act in question is likely a regulation for employment. The phrase gives a legal definition for the word *only as it is used in or by this Act*.

Because many words in most languages carry a subtext or connotation, the use of one specific word often implies a reference to only the things described by that word. However, in a legal document, it may be necessary to refer to several things which it applies to, without it being possible to list all of them every time they're referred to.

Thus, the word "industry" will be used by this Act to include also anything which is among the list of things quoted, and also anything which is considered a workplace. Now the Act doesn't have to state every single one of these things every time it refers to them, and further, it leaves no ambiguity in case one of those things was left out when it should have been included.